# Firebase database .on('value') method called even if child added in same level

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a newbie in using Firebase database. I am trying to store user login time in Firebase database. Sample code below.

```
const USER_LOGIN_TIME = "UserLoginTime";
  const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId")!;
  const spaceId = localStorage.getItem("spaceId")!;
  const loginTime = database.ref(`${spaceId}/${USER_LOGIN_TIME}/${userId}`);
  loginTime.set(time);
  loginTime.on('value', (snapshot: any) => {
    let latestTime = snapshot.val();
    // This is getting called even if some new user logs in
    // some logic goes here
  });
```

`loginTime` is stored properly.

I am assuming `.on('value')` will be called only if the value changes in `${spaceId}/${USER_LOGIN_TIME}/${userId}`.

But the issue is `.on('value')` method is getting called whenever there is new entry in `${spaceId}/${USER_LOGIN_TIME}`. New entry will be added when new user logs in a different browser.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here! Any help is appreciated.

**Update**
My Firebase DB schema:

`- <spaceID>
     - UserLoginTime
          - <UserID>
               - time: <timestamp>
          - <UserID>
               - time: <timestamp>`

Comment: Please add the schema of your database

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to Firebase, but it is my code. During the initial load, `spaceID` and `userId` is null for all users and time is set for `null` key. This gets updated whenever a new user logs in and old users in the same session will get the updates and hence logged out.